# Projection create new field

Tags: spring, spring-data

I have a class that represents a user date of birth in two separated fields

```
public class User {
    private int yearOfBirth;
    private int monthOfBirth;
}
```

Is it possible to make a projection that exports the user age? I know we can concatenate fields using [@Value](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.projections.hidden-data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to resolve the problem (if you can add code to the domain class) is to add a method in the user class like the one below:

```
@JsonIgnore
public int getAge() {
    return Period.between(
            LocalDate.of(dobYear, dobMonth, 1),
            LocalDate.now()
    ).getYears();
}
```

You can add the `@JsonIgnore` to block spring from exporting an "age" field when your entity is serialized. After adding that method you can create projection like the one below:

```
@Projection(name = "userAge ", types = {User.class})
public interface UserAge {

    @Value("#{target.getAge()}")
    Integer getAge();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, for example:

```
public class UserAgeDto {
    private int yearOfBirth;
    private int monthOfBirth;

    public UserAgeDto(int yearOfBirth, int monthOfBirth) {
        // constructor implementation...
    }

    public int getAge() {
        // age calculation...
    }
}

public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("select new com.example.myapp.dto.UserAgeDto(u.yearOfBirth, u.monthOfBirth) from User u where u = ?")
    UserAgeDto getUserAgeDto(User user);
}
```

Some [info](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_04/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_select_clause)

Comment: Thank you @Cepr0, but I was looking for a way to do this with a Projection

Comment: you can use UserAgeDto as the projection, as shown in the code.

Comment: @RafaelTeles You should give more info - what exactly you need, show your entities/repo, a template of the result you need...